# Why does size_of::<&T>() == size_of::<usize>() depend on whether T is Sized?

Tags: rust

[The docs for `size_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) say the following:

> If `T` is Sized, all of those types [pointer types such as `&T`] have the same size as `usize`.

Why that qualifier? Would a pointer not have a definitive size regardless of any property of the type being pointed to?

Comment: It is because there is fat pointers in rust, this might help: http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/the-sized-trait/

Comment: Because standard tell it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unsized object references have extra data in addition to the pointer to the object. In the case of slice references (`&[T]`), they contain a size in order to indicate how long this slice is. And in the case of references to traits (trait objects), they contain a pointer to a vtable in order to enable dynamic dispatch.

Comment: now that it's written down in front of me, it seems painfully obvious... I should have thought more carefully what kinds of unsized types there are. Thanks!